# Mul 2 number as Double and Int in Swift

Tags: swift

How to convert the following code from java to Swift, they have results different.

//Java

```
int x = 100;
x -= (0.65 * 19);
System.out.println(x);    // 87
```

//Swift

```
var z : Int = 100
z -= Int(0.65 * 19)
print(z)                 // 88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java mixed integer/double arithmetic, all operands
are converted to `double` first. So `x` is converted to a `double`, then `(0.65 * 19)` is subtracted (resulting in `87.65`), finally the result is truncated to an `int` (resulting in `87`) and assigned to `x` again.

There is no implicit type conversion in Swift. In

```
z -= Int(0.65 * 19)
```

you are truncating the result of the multiplication to `12`
*before* it is subtracted from `100`.

In order to get the same result as in Java, you have to do the
same conversions explicitly:

```
var z : Int = 100
z = Int(Double(z) - 0.65 * 19)
print(z) // 87
```